# How to open the file that is selected using Fileopendialog in javascript?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, fileopendialog

I am using a Html input tag with type="file" to allow the user to select a excel.

After the file is selected, where it will be stored?
From where can I get that file?
I want to read the file using javascript/jquery.

I searched a lot in net. But cannot find any solution for this..

Please help me..

Comment: Re-tagged as `asp.net` and `file-upload`

Answer (score 0):

Look, This is the basics. HTML is on the Client Side. if you want to read that excel file then write some insert code for the database and then you can find the same from the database.

and for the browse file look for the following cases

You want the `Application.GetOpenFilename` function. Copying from VBA Object Browser:

> Function GetOpenFilename([FileFilter], [FilterIndex], [Title], [ButtonText], [MultiSelect])
>       Member of Excel.Application

I think this info will help you to clear your basics, if you want to solve your specific doubt then ask the specific question.